PHP proc_open vs pcntl_fork performance
I want to run hundreds of parallel php processes from a PHP script. Which will provide better performance: proc_open or pcntl_fork?

proc_open() does lots of things to set up the process, create pipes, etc. pcntl_fork() just calls fork(). They're not really comparable.

If you need many of the features of proc_open(), doing them yourself in PHP code will almost certainly be slower, since it's interpreted.

And doing it yourself is also more error prone. The internal PHP code has been around for years and should be error-free.

"I want to run hundreds of parallel php processes" Why do you need to do that?

In general running more parallel processes than CPUs provides little benefit.

That should be almost trivial to measure. What is the data you collected on that, was it inconclusive in any way? Also, you haven't defined the environment in any way.

After testing  when using pcntl_fork the CPU is less loaded and works faster. Thanks for the answers.
